# Netsh в Windows не работает с прокси

Tags: windows, proxy, прокси, netsh, winhttp

Для анонимной работы с ПО настраиваю службу автоматического обнаружения веб-прокси WinHTTP: `netsh winhttp set proxy proxy_ip:port`. Убеждаюсь, что прокси добавился: `netsh winhttp show proxy`. Запускаю саму службу WinHTTP. Проверяю через прогу свой IP, трафик идет в обход службы WinHTTP. Прокси проверялся через Internet Explorer - 100% рабочий. Использую сторонний проксификатор, весь трафик уходит через прокси. Выходит проблема в WinHTTP. Буду благодарен за любой совет.

Comment: А если прописать в IE прокси, а затем импортнуть "netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie" - тоже не работает? И еще: машина в домене?

Comment: Импорт также не работает. Извиняюсь, но вопрос с доменом не совсем понял. Проверяю как на локальной Windows 7, так и на виртуальных машинах: Windows 7/Windows 8.

Comment: WinHTTP ведь работает с удаленными прокси?